# how to set up ldap and trac

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ldap, active-directory, trac

I have set up kerberos authentication with `trac` which works well. Now I want to use AD groups and users for `trac` permissions using the `trac` plugin [Configuration for `LdapPlugin`](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/LdapPlugin#Configuration). I have been following this guide but it is not working. I am using `trac 0.10.4`.

In my apache, I have the following:

```
<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
    AuthType Kerberos
    AuthName Trac
    KrbServiceName HTTP/intranet.domain.com
    KrbMethodNegotiate On
    KrbMethodK5Passwd On
    KrbAuthRealms DOMAIN.COM
    Krb5KeyTab /etc/httpd/conf/intranet.keytab
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    require valid-user
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</LocationMatch>
```

My `trac` configuration:

```
[root@hero plugins]# cat ../conf/trac.ini 
[components]
ldapplugin.* = enabled

[notification]
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
mime_encoding = base64
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc = sharif.uddin@domain.com
smtp_default_domain = domain.com
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac@domain.com
smtp_password =
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = support@domain.com
smtp_server = hero.uk.domain.com
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user =
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
#ignore_domain= domain.com

[ldap]
global_perms = true
enable = true
use_tls = false
host = echo
port = 389
basedn = dc=domain,dc=com

# Relative DN for users (defaults to none)
user_rdn = ou=TechSupport,ou=Woking,ou=Sites

# Relative DN for group of names (defaults to none)
group_rdn = cn=users

# objectclass for groups
#groupname = groupofnames

# dn entry in a groupname 
#groupmember = member

# attribute name for a group
#groupattr = cn

# attribute name for a user
#user_name_attr = uid

# objectclass for user ; customize to your needs
#user_class = sambaSamAccount

# attribute name to store trac permission
#permattr = tracperm

# filter to search for dn with 'permattr' attributes
#permfilter = objectclass=*

# time, in seconds, before a cached entry is purged out of the local cache.
#cache_ttl = 900

# maximum number of entries in the cache
#cache_size = 100

# whether to perform an authenticated bind for group resolution
#group_bind = false

# whether to perform an authenticated bind for permision store operations
store_bind = true

# user for authenticated connection to the LDAP directory
bind_user = cn=administrator,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com

# password for authenticated connection
bind_passwd = ********

# global permissions (vs. per-environment permissions)
#global_perms = false

# group permissions are managed as addition/removal to the LDAP directory groups
#manage_groups = true

# whether a group member contains the full dn or a simple uid
#groupmemberisdn = true

[trac]
permission_store = LdapPermissionStore
```

If I change the httpd configuration to `ldap` I get the following error:

```
[Mon Dec 02 14:13:33 2013] [warn] [client 172.16.0.85] [19659] auth_ldap authenticate: user sharifu authentication failed; URI /trac/paradox/login [ldap_search_ext_s() for user failed][Operations error], referer: http://intranet/trac/paradox/

<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName Trac
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://echo:389/dc=domain,dc=com?uid"
    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
    require valid-user
#     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
#     AllowOverride All
#     SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</LocationMatch>
```

I believe I am doing something wrong in the `trac.ini` file if I use kerberos authentication in apache.

I have now done the following and managed to get authentication working using `ldap` in apache. I just need some help implementing this into `trac` to use permission on AD groups etc.

```
<LocationMatch "/trac/[^/]+/login">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName Trac
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://echo.uk.domain.com akutan.usa.domain.com/ou=Sites,dc=domain,dc=com?sAMAccountName"
    AuthLDAPBindDN cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
    AuthLDAPBindPassword **********

    AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
    require valid-user
</LocationMatch>

[root@hero trac]# trac-admin paradox permission list

User             Action         
--------------------------------
@Administrators  TRAC_ADMIN     
anonymous        CHANGESET_VIEW 
anonymous        FILE_VIEW      
anonymous        LOG_VIEW       
anonymous        MILESTONE_VIEW 
anonymous        REPORT_SQL_VIEW
anonymous        REPORT_VIEW    
anonymous        ROADMAP_VIEW   
anonymous        SEARCH_VIEW    
anonymous        TICKET_VIEW    
anonymous        TIMELINE_VIEW  
anonymous        WIKI_VIEW      

Available actions:
 BROWSER_VIEW, CHANGESET_VIEW, CONFIG_VIEW, FILE_VIEW, LOG_VIEW,
 MILESTONE_ADMIN, MILESTONE_CREATE, MILESTONE_DELETE, MILESTONE_MODIFY,
 MILESTONE_VIEW, REPORT_ADMIN, REPORT_CREATE, REPORT_DELETE, REPORT_MODIFY,
 REPORT_SQL_VIEW, REPORT_VIEW, ROADMAP_ADMIN, ROADMAP_VIEW, SEARCH_VIEW,
 TICKET_ADMIN, TICKET_APPEND, TICKET_CHGPROP, TICKET_CREATE, TICKET_MODIFY,
 TICKET_VIEW, TIMELINE_VIEW, TRAC_ADMIN, WIKI_ADMIN, WIKI_CREATE,
 WIKI_DELETE, WIKI_MODIFY, WIKI_VIEW
```

I have forgotton to enable the plugins, however I am having trouble `trac` talking to `ldap`. In the log, I get the following:

```
Trac[paradox:api] ERROR: LDAP error: Operations error
Trac[paradox:api] ERROR: LDAP error: Operations error
Trac[paradox:api] DEBUG: Updating wiki page index
```

Current config:

```
[notification]
always_notify_owner = true
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
mime_encoding = base64
smtp_always_bcc =
smtp_always_cc = sharif.uddin@domain.com
smtp_default_domain = domain.com
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac@domain.com
smtp_password =
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = support@domain.com
smtp_server = hero.uk.domain.com
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user =
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
#ignore_domains = domain.com

[ldap]
enable = true
host = echo
basedn = dc=domain,dc=com
user_rdn = ou=Sites,dc=domain,dc=com
group_rdn = cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
store_bind = true
bind_user = Administrator@domain.com
bind_passwd = ******

[trac]
permission_store = LdapPermissionStore

[logging]
#log_file = /var/log/trac.log
log_format = Trac[$(basename)s:$(module)s] $(levelname)s: $(message)s
#log_level = DEBUG
#log_type = file

[components]
webadmin.* = enabled
ldapplugin.* = enabled
```

Comment: Please clarify "not working". What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what is actually happening? Do you get any error messages? Have you checked the Apache error log, the system error log, and possibly the LDAP server logs?

Comment: @derobert updated question